# Quillen groupoid of a groupoid.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

For any category $\mathcal{C}$ we can define its Quillen's groupoid, denoted $\mathcal{Q}(\mathcal{C})$, as the category which have the same objects than $\mathcal{C}$ and the arrows between two objects are $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{Q}(\mathcal{C})}(c, c^\prime)=\frac{\operatorname{Path}_\mathcal{C}(c, c^\prime)}{\sim}$.

Where $\operatorname{Path}_{\mathcal{C}}(c, c^\prime)$ is the set of all paths between $c$ and $c^\prime$ (it means the splice of an arbitrary finite set  of arrows without notice if are pointing to the right or to the left, but the first object must be $c$ and the last one $c^\prime$).

And the relation $\sim$ is the generated equivalence relation for this one:

two paths of gap length one are elementary homotopic if one is obtained from the other replacing a morphism occurring as one side of a commutative triangle by the others two sides, pointing in the appropiate directions.

The question is, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a groupoid (a category with all its arrows being isomorphisms) then $\mathcal{Q}(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: It appears to me that the Quillen groupoid can be described more abstractly as the universal groupoid generated by a category. In which case the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @ZhenLin Could you tell me where I can find the definition of fundamental groupoid generated by a category? Because I'm not being successful with that.
I proved that the Quillen groupoid satisfy a certain universal property, but with that I can prove that the Quillen groupoid of a category is equivalent with itself, but not necessarily the same.

Comment: The universal property of the "Quillen groupoid" construction (see more discussion of the terminology [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193400/non-abelian-grothendieck-group)) is that it is left adjoint to the inclusion functor from groupoids to categories. When the right adjoint of an adjoint pair is fully faithful, as in this case, it is a standard exercise (which should be in any introductory category theory text) to show that the unit of the adjunction is an isomorphism, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The comments (which should have been posted as answers) contain more general statements. If $\mathcal{C}$ is a groupoid, then you can explicitly write down an equivalence $\mathcal{C} \simeq Q(\mathcal{C})$. There is always a canonical functor $\mathcal{C} \to Q(\mathcal{C})$ which is bijective on objects. So it remains to check that it is fully faithful when $\mathcal{C}$ is a groupoid. Fullness: If $c=c_0 \leftarrow c_1  \rightarrow c_2 \leftarrow \dotsc \rightarrow c_n = c'$ is a path from $c$ to $c'$, it is induced by the morphism $c = c_0 \to c_1 \to c_2 \dotsc \to c_n = c'$ in $\mathcal{C}$, where we have inverted the arrows $\leftarrow$ to get arrows $\rightarrow$. Faithfulness can be done by "induction" on the definition of the number of steps used in the generated equivalence relation.